# Can't access winforms label after await?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a long running method which I made async.  I made my button click handler async as well, but when I try to access my label in my button click after the long method is done, it tells me it can't can't access it from another thread. Here is the code:

```
    private void Migrate()
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= excelData.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            var poco = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

            foreach (var column in distributionColumnExcelHeaderMappings)
            {
                if (column.ColumnIndex > 0)
                {
                    var value = excelData[i,column.ColumnIndex]?.ToString();

                    poco.Add(column.DistributionColumnName.Replace(" ", ""), value);
                }

            }

            pocos.Add(poco);
        }

            migrationRepository.BulkInsert(insertToTable, "Id", pocos);
    }

    private async void btnMigrate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = new Task(()=> Migrate());
        task.Start();
        lblStatus.Text = "Migrating data....";

        await task;

        lblStatus.Text = "Migration Complete";
    }
```

When the button is clicked, I see the status `Migrating data....`.  When that is complete, it throws an error on `lblStatus.Text = "Migration Complete"`.  I thought after await, it goes back to the UI thread?

I cleared out most of the code and it still throws the same error.  This is a VSTO excel add-in.  Could that be part of the problem?

```
private void Migrate()
{

}

private async void btnMigrate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Task.Run(()=>Migrate());
lblStatus.Text = "Done"; //still get error here
}
```

Comment: Changing the click handler doesnt change the label (or the thread it was created on).

Comment: Use `Task.Run`, do not create a `Task` yourself.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is not [MCVE] as this code should work fine (whether using `.Start` or `.Run`). Are you sure there is no `ConfigureAwait(false)` somewhere in your actual code? Can you post complete sample (replacing `Migrate` with just `Sleep`)?

Comment: I agree with @AlexeiLevenkov I've just tried to replicate this issue, and everything is working fine. The only thing I changed was the Migrate function performs a sleep for 1s.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  - that is literally the code...There is not ConfigureAwait(false).

Comment: Always nice to down vote when you don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and update your code to the following:

Instead of creating your task and then starting it manually, update it to just await on Task.Run:

```
private async void btnMigrate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Migrating data....";

    await Task.Run(()=> Migrate());

    lblStatus.Text = "Migration Complete";
}
```

**Edit:**

You can use a helper method that will check to see if the label needs to be invoked before updating.

```
private async void btnMigrate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetLabelText(lblStatus, "Migrating data....");

    await Task.Run(()=> Migrate());

    SetLabelText(lblStatus, "Migration complete.");
}

private void SetLabelText(Label label, string text)
{
    if (label.InvokeRequired)
    {
        label.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() {label.Text = text;});    
    }
    else
    {
        label.Text = text; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `Task.Run` as the single statement of a method is discouraged.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto can you explain why it is discouraged rather than just saying it is?

Comment: Because that's not asynchronous per-se. You are forcing synchronous code to run on another thread instead of leaving that decision to the client of the method

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for the explanation.. ended up updating the answer, though i may suspect it may be another issue

Comment: can you post the exception?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblStatus' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: @xaisoft see update. I am not really sure what is going on, especially if you dont have ConfigureAwait set. after awaiting, the UI thread should return, but it looks like it is not. I added a method to simply check if the label needs to be invoked before updating

Comment: @d.moncada - OK that worked.  Thanks for the help.  Any idea what might be causing it not to return to the UI thread?

Comment: sort of hard to tell since we dont have the entire codebase. there are no UI elements being accessed in your Migrate method, right? also, your btnMigrate_Click handler is strictly from a button click and nothing else, correct?

Comment: I updated my post. As you can see I took away most of the code. It is an VTSO excel add-in, so I am not sure if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: It had to do with the way office plugins handle async.  Your code works as well as doing `if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());`